# Simplifying hypergeometric function 4F3

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions

I am trying to make Mathematica simplify the following expression below.

```
FullSimplify[
 HypergeometricPFQ[{-(1/3), 1/3, -(1/2) - m, -m}, {1/2, 1/3 - m, 
   2/3 - m}, 1]
 , Assumptions -> Element[m, Integers] && m >= 1]
```

This results in some error, complaining about `Gamma[-3m]`being ComplexInfinity.

It seems that this should always be -1/2, for any positive integer value of $m$.
If there is some general formula which can evaluate the above, I would be happy for that too.

Comment: `Table[HypergeometricPFQ[{-(1/3), 1/3, -(1/2) - m, -m}, {1/2, 1/3 - m, 2/3 - m}, 1], {m, 10^3}]` seems pretty evidently true.

Comment: @Roman Right - which is why I would like to prove it. If Mathematica can understand it, it's likely a special case of some more general formula.

Comment: Have you looked through the [formulas](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/HypergeometricPFQ/03/01/05/) for $_{q+1}F_q(z=1)$? There seem to be lots of known special cases; maybe some of them aren't in Mathematica's database.